# Yaw, pitch, and roll rotations to six float variables

Tags: lua, calculus, angle

I need help creating a function to convert three angles (in degrees, yaw pitch and roll) to six float variables.

How would I go about making a function output these floats?

- {0, 0, 0} = {1, 0, 0, -0, -0, 1}
- {45, 0, 0} = {0.70710676908493, 0.70710676908493, 0, -0, -0, 1}
- {0, 90, 0} = {-4.3711388286738e-08, 0, 1, -1, 0, -4.3711388286738e-08}
- {0, 0, 135} = {1, -0, 0, -0, -0.70710676908493, -0.70710676908493}
- {180, 180, 0} = {1, -8.7422776573476e-08, 8.7422776573476e-08, 8.7422776573476e-08, 0, -1}
- {225, 0, 225} = {-0.70710682868958, 0.5, 0.5, -0, 0.70710670948029, -0.70710682868958}
- {270, 270, 270} = {1.4220277639103e-16, -2.3849761277006e-08, 1, 1, 1.1924880638503e-08, 1.42202776319103e-16}
- {315, 315, 315} = {0.5, -0.85355341434479, 0.14644680917263, 0.70710688829422, 0.5, 0.5}

**MORE EXAMPLES REQUESTED BY: Egor Skriptunoff**

- {10, 20, 30} = {0.92541658878326, -0.018028322607279, 0.37852230668068, -0.34202012419701, -0.46984630823135, 0.81379765272141}
- {10, 30, 20} = {0.85286849737167, -0.0052361427806318, 0.52209949493408, -0.5, -0.29619812965393, 0.81379765272141}
- {20, 10, 30} = {0.92541658878326, 0.21461015939713, 0.3123245537281, -0.17364817857742, -0.49240386486053, 0.85286849737167}
- {20, 30, 10} = {0.81379765272141, 0.25523611903191, 0.52209949493408, -0.5, -0.15038372576237, 0.85286849737167}
- {30, 10, 20} = {0.85286849737167, 0.41841205954552, 0.3123245537281, -0.17364817857742, -0.33682405948639, 0.92541658878326}
- {30, 20, 10} = {0.81379765272141, 0.4409696161747, 0.37852230668068, -0.34202012419701, -0.16317591071129, 0.92541658878326}

The code I currently have can calculate all of the floats except the 2nd and 3rd.

```
function convert_rotations(Yaw, Pitch, Roll)
    return {
        math.cos(math.rad(Yaw))*math.cos(math.rad(Pitch)),
        0,
        0,
        math.sin(math.rad(Pitch))*-1,
        math.sin(math.rad(Roll))*math.cos(math.rad(Pitch))*-1,
        math.cos(math.rad(Roll))*math.cos(math.rad(Pitch))
    }
end
```

I cannot seem to find the correct math for when all angles are nonzero for the 2nd float and 3rd float, but I did come up with this:

```
-- The second float when the Yaw is 0 degrees
math.sin(math.rad(Pitch))*math.sin(math.rad(Roll))*-1

-- The second float when the Pitch is 0 degrees
math.sin(math.rad(Yaw))*math.cos(math.rad(Roll))

-- The second float when the Roll is 0 degrees
math.sin(math.rad(Yaw))*math.sin(math.rad(Pitch))
```

And for the 3rd float I came up with this:

```
-- The third float when Yaw is 0 degrees
math.sin(math.rad(Pitch))*math.cos(math.rad(Roll))

-- The third float when Pitch is 0 degrees
math.sin(math.rad(Yaw))*math.sin(math.rad(Roll))

-- The third float when Roll is 0 degrees
math.cos(math.rad(Yaw))*math.sin(math.rad(Pitch))
```

Comment: What is the question here exactly? The math? The code? Something else? Have you tried anything for this yet?

Comment: How would I go about making a function output these floats? The math I assume involves math.rad, math.cos, math.sin and math.tan, but I'm unsure how all of it would come together in general.

Comment: Do you have these inputs in some format? Are those tables? Do you know what the math involved is? Can you write/have you written/do you have a library for the math?

Comment: The inputs are in degrees for yaw, pitch, and roll rotations. I believe the output are matrices. I have code that can do the math of the first two floats, but only when the pitch and roll rotations are set to 0. The math is {math.cos(math.rad(yaw)), math.sin(math.rad(yaw))}.

Comment: The output does not exactly look like matrices. If it were matrices, they'd need to be 4x4 (so even if we assumed no translation, we'd still end up with nine values). Six values would work in 2D, but then we wouldn't need three angles. Can you tell us where you got the examples? Is this some kind of work for university?

Comment: No, it's not for university. It's actually for a script to change the rotation of 3D objects in a game. I updated my post with my current code, but still have issues with a couple float values.

Comment: Can you post more examples?  Please show answers for these inputs: `10,20,30`, `10,30,20`, `20,10,30`, `20,30,10`, `30,10,20`, `30,20,10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local function Rotate(X, Y, alpha)
    local c, s = math.cos(math.rad(alpha)), math.sin(math.rad(alpha))
    local t1, t2, t3 = X[1]*s, X[2]*s, X[3]*s
    X[1], X[2], X[3] = X[1]*c+Y[1]*s, X[2]*c+Y[2]*s, X[3]*c+Y[3]*s
    Y[1], Y[2], Y[3] = Y[1]*c-t1, Y[2]*c-t2, Y[3]*c-t3
end

local function convert_rotations(Yaw, Pitch, Roll)
    local F, L, T = {1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,1}
    Rotate(F, L, Yaw)
    Rotate(F, T, Pitch)
    Rotate(T, L, Roll)
    return {F[1], -L[1], -T[1], -F[3], L[3], T[3]}
end
```